# What is the appropriate way to deliver a notification intent to an Android activity if it is in the foreground and otherwise start it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Android documentation states that if an Activity's launch mode is declared to be `singleTop`, then starting this activity with an intent that has the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`should deliver a notification intent if this Activity is already running; otherwise it will start a new instance of this Activity.

While I do not fully understand how this setting does the trick, it does work except in one scenario: If the user started this activity and then navigated to a child activity, then the application does not bring back the original activity on receiving the intent described above.

How can I get around this problem by bringing back the original activity in this case also?

As always, thank you all very much for helping out!!

Answer (score 1):

Does the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP suit your needs?  It finishes all the other children between your current activity and activity you're launching in the stack, but otherwise seems to behave the way you'd like.

Comment: There's also `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BRING_TO_FRONT` if you want to keep the rest of the stack.